# Save images from array to folder

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem here in saving images from an array. Well I have a multiple array using AJAX POST to PHP(codeigniter). What I want to do is to save multiple row of images from html table to my desired folder path. Do you know how to achieve this or a way?

This is the code in saving

```
$('#save').click(function(){

 var image_data = [];
 $('#list tbody tr').each(function (row, tr){
    if ($(tr).find('td:eq(0) img').data('file_name') != '') {
          image_len[row] = {
               'image_len' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0) img').data('file_name')
          }
     }
     });
         console.log(image_data);
         console.log(my_other_data1);
         console.log(my_other_data2);

})
```

This is the result in image_data

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
     0: {image_len: "C:\fakepath\asd.png"}
     1: {image_len: "C:\fakepath\123.png"}
```

This is my AJAX

```
    var data = {
      my_other_data1: my_other_data1,
      my_other_data2: my_other_data2,
      image_data: image_data
    };
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('My_Controller/save'); ?>",
      dataType: 'json',
      crossOrigin: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
      },
      success: function(result) {
      },
      failure: function(msg) {
        console.log("Failure to connect to server!");
      },
      error: function(status) {},
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.onprogress = function(evt) {
          $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
        };
        xhr.onloadend = function(evt) {
          $("body").css("cursor", "default");
        };
        return xhr;
      }
    });
```

Comment: You'd need to use server-side code - vanilla (DOM/client-side/browser) JS can't access the directory structure unless maliciously injected.

Comment: I included my AJAX. Please see above code. I dont want to use JS to access the directory. I want my PHP to access it then store the images.